# C# Search for string in an array of classes that include arrays of classes

Tags: c#, arrays

I am working my way through a C# course so this question is more academic than real world.

I want to search for string in an array of classes that includes one or more subsidiary (embedded)array of classes.  I want to be able to search both the parent and the subsidiary arrays.  I've been trying the NET Framework Class Library Array Methods but am getting nowhere - you'll see my  Array.IndexOf returns -1.  I've pasted my code below and would be grateful for any advice.  I know there are more sophisticated ways to do this but I need to stick with arrays for the time being.  Thanks in advance.

```
using System;

namespace Nested_Arrays 
{
    public class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            Student[] StudentArray = new Student[3];
            StudentSubjects[] StudentSubjectsArray = new StudentSubjects[3];

            StudentArray[0] = new Student() {
                StudentName = "Peter", StudentLocation = "Australia"
            };
            StudentArray[0].StudentSubjectsArray[0] = new StudentSubjects() {
                SubjectName = "Calculus", StudentsResult = "Pass"
            };
            StudentArray[0].StudentSubjectsArray[1] = new StudentSubjects() {
                SubjectName = "Algebra", StudentsResult = "Pass"
            };
            StudentArray[0].StudentSubjectsArray[2] = new StudentSubjects() {
                SubjectName = "Statistics", StudentsResult = "Pass"
            };
            StudentArray[1] = new Student() {
                StudentName = "Michelle", StudentLocation = "France"
            };
            StudentArray[1].StudentSubjectsArray[0] = new StudentSubjects() {
                SubjectName = "Engineering", StudentsResult = "Pass"
            };
            StudentArray[1].StudentSubjectsArray[1] = new StudentSubjects() {
                SubjectName = "Algebra", StudentsResult = "Pass"
            };
            StudentArray[1].StudentSubjectsArray[2] = new StudentSubjects() {
                SubjectName = "Aramaic", StudentsResult = "Pass"
            };
            StudentArray[2] = new Student() {
                StudentName = "Mitchell", StudentLocation = "Canada"
            };
            StudentArray[2].StudentSubjectsArray[0] = new StudentSubjects() {
                SubjectName = "Engineering", StudentsResult = "Pass"
            };
            StudentArray[2].StudentSubjectsArray[1] = new StudentSubjects() {
                SubjectName = "Greek", StudentsResult = "Pass"
            };
            StudentArray[2].StudentSubjectsArray[2] = new StudentSubjects() {
                SubjectName = "Aramaic", StudentsResult = "Pass"
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine($ "\n{i + 1,3}  {StudentArray[i].StudentName,-10} {StudentArray[i].StudentLocation,-15}");
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    Console.WriteLine($ "{j + 1,6}  {StudentArray[i].StudentSubjectsArray[j].SubjectName,-15} {StudentArray[i].StudentSubjectsArray[j].StudentsResult,-10}");
                }
            }
            String searchString = "Mitchell";
            Console.WriteLine($ "\n We are searching for \"{searchString}\"");
            int index = Array.IndexOf(StudentArray, searchString);
            Console.WriteLine(" The first occurrence of \"{0}\" is at index {1}.", searchString, index);
            searchString = "Aramaic";
            Console.WriteLine($ "\n We are searching for \"{searchString}\"");
            index = Array.IndexOf(StudentSubjectsArray, searchString);
            Console.WriteLine(" The first occurrence of \"{0}\" is at index {1}.", searchString, index);
            Console.WriteLine($ "\n");
        }

        public class Student 
        {
            private string studentName;
            public string StudentName {
                get {
                    return studentName;
                }
                set {
                    studentName = value;
                }
            }

            private string studentLocation;
            public string StudentLocation {
                get {
                    return studentLocation;
                }
                set {
                    studentLocation = value;
                }
            }

            private StudentSubjects[] studentSubjectsArray = new StudentSubjects[3];
            public StudentSubjects[] StudentSubjectsArray {
                get {
                    return studentSubjectsArray;
                }
                set {
                    studentSubjectsArray = value;
                }
            }

            //Constructor
            public Student() {}
        }

        public class StudentSubjects {
            private string subjectName;
            public string SubjectName {
                get {
                    return subjectName;
                }
                set {
                    subjectName = value;
                }
            }

            private string studentsResult;
            public string StudentsResult {
                get {
                    return studentsResult;
                }
                set {
                    studentsResult = value;
                }
            }

            //Constructor
            public StudentSubjects() {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx) searches for the specified object and returns the index of its first occurrence in a one-dimensional array.

In your case you need to search for object properties and find an index of matched object. I suggest use use `Linq` to search for an object that matches property value and then search for an index of an object (as follows).

```
var item = StudentArray.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.StudentName.Equals(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
                                        || x.StudentSubjectsArray.Any(s=>s.SubjectName.Equals(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));

if(item!= null)  
   index = Array.IndexOf(StudentArray, item);
```

Check this working [`demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GQb7a3)

Answer (score 0):

I think that I've finally did it , it took me a wile, because i'm a novice.. 
   So,

1) first off all I added two lists of strings in each Class 
   like:

```
      public class StudentSubjects
          {
              public List<String> studentsubjectlist = new List<string>();
```

and

```
public class StudentSubjects
    {
    public List<String> studentsubjectlist = new List<string>();
```

then you will need to add all your propertys to those lists, by using "Set" accessor of the property:

```
 public string StudentName
                 {
                 get
                  {
                    return studentName;
                  }

                 set
                 {
                     studentName = value;
                     studentslist.Add(value);
                 }
             }
```

If you do debugging in this stage you will see there is a list in every object in the array, that contains all the propertys of the Object.

2) Your index has to be an Array because it will contain more then one number:

```
int[] index = new int[StudentArray.Length];
```

3) Now we can loop.

```
    int i;
    int j;
    int x;

    for ( i = 0; i < StudentArray.Length; i++)
    {

       for ( j = 0; j < StudentArray[i].studentslist.Count; j++)

        {

            if (StudentArray[i].studentslist[j] == searchString)
            {
                index[0] = i;
                index[1] = -1;
                index[2] = j;
                break;
            }
        }

       for ( x = 0, j = 0; j < StudentArray[i].StudentSubjectsArray[x].studentsubjectlist.Count; j++)
        {

            if (StudentArray[i].StudentSubjectsArray[x].studentsubjectlist[j] == searchString)

            {
                index[0] = i;
                index[1] = x;
                index[2] = j;
                break;
            }

  else if (j == StudentArray[i].StudentSubjectsArray [x].studentsubjectlist.Count)          
            {
                x++;
                j = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

4)Pay attention that:

int i is a index of the Student in the Array,

int x is a index of the StudentSubject, if searchword is inside of Student object and not inside StudentSubject, x will return -1.

int j is a index of property inside of List.

5) You will also need to change your Console.Writeline to:

```
 Console.WriteLine( "\n We are searching for \"{searchString}\"");
   Console.WriteLine(" The first occurrence of \"{0}\" is at index {1}.{2}. {3}.", searchString, index[0], index[1], index[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks Rodion.
StudentArray[i].GetType().ToString() returns "TestingForumResponses.Program+Student" so your ifs don't fire and your code just drops through.
I'm not quite how to make use of the .GetType - any advice?

Comment: I've changeg the solution completly. Now it should work.